# Difference between GSO and GO similitude groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, algebraic-groups

My understanding is that the similitude groups $\mathrm{GO}(V), \mathrm{GSp}(V)$, etc. relative to the usual groups $\mathrm{O}(V), \mathrm{Sp}(V)$, etc. are sort of analogous to the relationship between the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ and the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}(V)$.

The similitude groups and general linear group allow for homothety or multiplication by a unit of norm possibly greater than $1$ (e.g. by $\mathbb{C}^\times$ if we're talking about a complex vector space $V$).

What is the relationship between $\mathrm{GSO}(V)$ and $\mathrm{GO}(V)$ then? How are these different?

Comment: You seem to be muddling up the orthogonal similitude group $GSO$ and the symplectic similitude group $GSp$ -- they're quite different beasts, one corresponding to  a symmetric bilinear form and the other to an antisymmetric one.

Comment: @David Loeffler I am asking about the difference between $\mathrm{GO}(V)$ and $\mathrm{GSO}(V)$. Aren't they both orthogonal similitude groups? The former is mentioned [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081080500209588) and the latter is mentioned [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/ert/2014-18-03/S1088-4165-2014-00451-5/S1088-4165-2014-00451-5.pdf).

Comment: Both are mentioned together [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04897).

Comment: The group $O(V)$ has two components, and $SO(V)$ is the identity component. Similarly, if $V$ has even dimension, then $GO(V)$ has two components and $GSO(V)$ is the identity component. (In the odd-dimensional case $GO(V)$ is connected).